# Windows Phone 8 Media Framework Yume Advertisement

Tags: c#

I am using Microsoft.PlayerFramework.MediaPlayer for play the advertisement.
using mediaplayer.PlayAd() method am using to play the advertisement for normal ads.
Incase of custom ads that is vast complaint,When we play an advertisement application
and move to dormant state.After resuming the application we are not able to restore the advertisement state for vast complaint ads where as we use  player.RestoreMediaState().
We need to know are there any ways to do for Custom ads.We have even went through Player Documentation and still trying for a fix.

http://playerframework.codeplex.com/documentation

Let us know if someone has faced this problem and know how we can handle this scenario.

Regards,
Harish